# In the execution of an insert, when are default DATETIME values retrieved?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm dealing with a scenario where two inserts are being done on the same table in separate concurrently executing processes. Table structure is fairly simple.

> There's an IDENTITY ID column and UpdateDateTime column with a DEFAULT
>   constraint of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Normal expectations are that a record with a higher ID will have the same or a later timestamp. In one scenario, we see a record with a **higher ID value but with an UpdateDateTime 2 minutes** prior to that record.

I think what has to be happening is that the one record retrieved the **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** but held onto it for a couple minutes (due to blocking) until it could finally perform this insert. However, my understanding is that the DEFAULT value is recorded at the time of insert and not before. Am I on the right track? At what point during execution is a DEFAULT value retrieved?

Comment: There is no "default value". When you select getdate() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP it gets the value when it runs. Thus you could see the behavior you are discussing if there is some blocking on the first one. Even though the insert started earlier it could have a later datetime value.

Comment: @SeanLange My question is at what point in the execution of the insert is the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP executed and recorded? If it is recorded the moment an insert is performed leaving that record in a committable state, then I don't think it would be possible to see the scenario I'm seeing: record inserted later (by IDENTITY value) with an earlier DEFAULT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) value.

Comment: For the sake for argument let's say you have a procedure with nothing but a single insert statement and that insert is using a select statement to retrieve the values. The value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is when the select is run. If there is a lock on the table the insert must wait until that lock is released. At that point the select statement would execute. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @SeanLange Not exactly. The table LOG_RECORDS has an IDENTITY(1,1) column called `ID` and it has a DEFAULT constraint: 
`DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FOR UpdateDateTime`

Insert query is not explicitly inserting a value, allowing the default constraint to set the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on insert:
`INSERT INTO LOG_UPDATES (TrxnID, UpdateCode)`

The resulting problem is that a record in the table with a higher IDENTITY value has an _earlier_ UpdateDateTime, while both had UpdateDateTimes assigned by the DEFAULT constraint. So it seems that the second record was inserted later (by the ID).

Comment: Perhaps you should share the ddl for your table and the insert process? I am guessing blindly as to how you have this working.

Comment: I would recommend switching to UTC functions, otherwise you will repeatedly observe this behaviour around the DST time change in autumn :)